# How do I reverse this copy process?

Tags: java, android

I can copy my app's data using code from the `root/data/data/com.teenchat` to `sdcard/download`

```
String comando = "cp -r /data/data/com.teenchat /sdcard/Download";
```

but the the app doesn't recognize the data (though it doesn't close) when I paste it back using the code

```
String comando = "cp -r /sdcard/Download/com.teenchat /data/data";
```

I can manually do both the tasks 1) backup 2) restore the data and it works just fine! but when I try to do task 1 via code and do task 2 manually, it fails to recognize. I have checked the data's size in both cases it is the same.

Here is my full code for reference -

```
//String comando = "cp -r /data/data/com.teenchat /sdcard/Download";
    String comando = "cp -r /sdcard/Download/com.teenchat /data/data";
    Process suProcess = null;
    try {
        suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
    try {
        os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
     int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
     if (255 != suProcessRetval)
     {

     }else
     {

     }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     Log.w("Error ejecutando el comando Root", ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What about permissions and ownerships?

Comment: Are the permissions correct after the copying? Try `cp -a` instead of `cp -r`...

Comment: it is not working mate